# spin_lock_irqsave() in interrupt context

Tags: c, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I'm maintaining a driver which shares some resource between the ISR (i.e., in interrupt context) and the `read()` syscall.  In both cases, `spin_lock_irqsave()` is used, since (obviously) the resource can be acquired in the interrupt context.

However, I was wondering if using `spin_lock_irqsave()` is necessary in the interrupt context.  Namely, the Unreliable Guide to Locking (see here: https://kernel.readthedocs.io/en/sphinx-samples/kernel-locking.html) states:

> Note that the `spin_lock_irqsave()` will turn off interrupts if they are on, otherwise does nothing (if we are already in an interrupt handler), hence these functions are safe to call from any context.

As a result, is it common practice to use "normal" `spin_lock()` in the interrupt handler (since the particular interrupt is already disabled) and then call `spin_lock_irqsave()` in the user context?  Alternatively, is the better practice to just use `spin_lock_irqsave()` everywhere?  I'm leaning towards the latter, for two reasons:

1. As soon as someone sees that a lock is acquired with `spin_lock_irqsave()`, it's obvious that the lock is intended to be shared with the interrupt context.
2. As someone maintaining the code, you don't have to ensure whether or not a particular function is going to be called in what context.  Said differently, using `spin_lock_irqsave()` works in any context, so you don't have to ensure that a function is only called in a certain context.

With the above said, I'm wondering what the convention/best practice is for code that resides in kernel space.  Is it better to use `spin_lock_irqsave()` everywhere the lock is acquired, even if you can guarantee that the lock is being acquired from the interrupt context?

Comment: It is safe to use `spin_lock` instead of `spin_lock_irqsave` in interrupt context. However, by doing this you *may* have a problem with reusing the code: a code which uses non-irq version of spinlock cannot be used in normal(non-interrupt) context. If you don't plan to reuse your ISR code in other places, `spin_lock` is OK.

Comment: `spin_lock` basically will protect from reentering the portion of IRQ handler only. Another CPU in the system may touch same date outside of IRQ context at the same time and IRQ might be triggered. If you use non-irq version of spin lock in some other function, data corruption is warranted.

Answer (score 1):

See [Unreliable Guide To Locking](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/kernel-hacking/locking.html) in kernel documentation. There's a [table of minimum requirements for locking](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/kernel-hacking/locking.html#table-of-minimum-requirements) to synchronize between different contexts which, roughly speaking, can be summarized as:

1. If one of them is a process: use the ones that are strong enough to disable the other. For example if the other competitor is a softirq, then you need at
   least `spin_lock_bh`, which disables softirq while locking.
2. Else if one of the them is hard irq: the advent of hard irq is inevitable unless you disable it beforehand, so `spin_lock_irq` or `spin_lock_irqsave`, depending on whether the other is hard irq or not.
3. Otherwise, use `spin_lock`.

(Of course, those are under assumption that your kernel isn't config as `PREEMPT_RT`)